# How can I delete images without labels (label `<none>`) using podman?

Tags: podman

When I run `podman images`, I see a bunch of images like this,

```
$ podman images
REPOSITORY                 TAG        IMAGE ID      CREATED       SIZE
localhost/tcms             latest     e6d31cbc5385  10 hours ago  86.4 MB
<none>                     <none>     8f773eba96cd  10 hours ago  86.4 MB
<none>                     <none>     3e335f6f49fe  13 hours ago  93.9 MB
<none>                     <none>     6e41c1796a0f  13 hours ago  93.9 MB
<none>                     <none>     bdde160250db  13 hours ago  93.3 MB
<none>                     <none>     d323538cae8f  13 hours ago  93.3 MB
```

How can I remove those images where the label is `<none>` en masse? I don't see command that does this under `podman images --help`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However insane the design decision

- `podman images`
- `podman image`

are different commands, you'll want to use

```
podman image prune
```

Which will remove unused images with a label of `<NONE>`. If you add the `-a` flag it will remove all images, even those with a label, if they're unused by a container.